# How to get a IAM access key's creation date via the AWS JS SDK

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

When accessing AWS via its Management Console it's possible to see the date when a IAM `access key` was created.

How can I access that information for a specific key via the AWS JS SDK?

Comment: My answer to https://stackoverflow.com/q/72798104/13400729 also answers this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `listAccessKeys({UserName: '<username>'})` method returns the following information for each of the User's access keys:

```
{
  UserName: '<username>',
  AccessKeyId: '<key id>',
  Status: '<status>',
  CreateDate: '<date key created>'
}
```

Which includes the date the access key was created.

credit to [@Parsifal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13400729/parsifal)