# How can I check if a IAM access key is active via the AWS JS SDK

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-iam, aws-sdk-js

When using the AWS Management Console its easy to check whether a IAM access key is active or not.

How can I check if a IAM access key is active via the AWS JS SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API call [ListAccessKeys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_ListAccessKeys.html) will return information about all of a user's access keys, including creation date (which answers your other question). There's also [GetAccessKeyLastUsed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_GetAccessKeyLastUsed.html), which as its name indicates tells you when a key was last used.

I don't use the JS SDK, so these functions might not exist there, but look under the IAM module.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to retrieve that, you can check if the key is available but not if active or not

[API_GetAccessKeyInfo](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetAccessKeyInfo.html)

> This operation does not indicate the state of the access key. The key might be active, inactive, or deleted. Active keys might not have permissions to perform an operation. Providing a deleted access key might return an error that the key doesn't exist.